# Client Server File transfer in C

Tags: c, client, server

I am developing a client server file transfer program in C in which I need to find a file saved in the server directory and send the file requested by a particular client. Could someone please help me what are the commands or what the program should be ?
Especially how to search for a file(string recvd from client) in server directory and send to client.

The focus of my program is more on the programming part of Server using TCP only. The file searching part is particularly important for me and Im not getting it: say a client wishes to download a filename "string" which is previously stored in its directory on the server for instance: home/server1/client1/filename; the server SEARCHES the file and sends it to client1 in C
Many Thanks.

Comment: To start, for security, only files in the 'public' directory should be allowed to be transferred to a client.

Answer (score 0):

```
There are several file transfer protocols already available.  
I would suggest TFTP (Trivial File Transfer Protocol) 
as it is (relatively) simple to implement 
and robust enough to get the job done, even in noisy environments.  
It is a 'lock step' protocol, 
where the sender invokes a timeout when a block is sent, 
if the timeout occurs without receiving an ack/blocknum response from the receiver,
then the same block is re-sent.
checksums are used by the receiver to validate each block
The details are in: <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying; the focus of my program is more on the programming part of Server using TCP only. The file searching part is particularly important for me and Im not getting it: say a client wishes to download a filename "string" which is previously stored in its directory on the server for instance: home/server1/client1/filename; the server SEARCHES the file and sends it to client1 in C

Comment: the fopen() statement would handle that and it lets the code know if the file does not exist.  HOWEVER; this would allow ANY client file to be transferred, including the html, php, etc files  which is a serious security breach.